# Widget Spacing in GTK

Tags: haskell, gtk

I'm having difficulty getting widgets to space properly with GTK, I'm trying to make a simple window that displays a `TextView` in the majority of the window, and has a little bar at the top with a few buttons. I'm thinking something like this:

```
------------------------------
-                            -
------------------------------
-                            -
-                            -
-                            -
-                            -
-                            -
------------------------------
```

But GTK is actually giving me something more like this:

```
-----------------------------
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-----------------------------
-                           -
-                           -
-                           -
-----------------------------
```

I don't want the respective boxes to be split in half like that. How can I fix my code?

```
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initGUI
    window    <- windowNew
    windowBox <- vBoxNew True 2
    menuBox   <- hBoxNew True 2
    buttonOne <- buttonNewWithLabel "Button 1"
    buttonTwo <- buttonNewWithLabel "Button 2"
    textBuf   <- textBufferNew Nothing
    textView  <- textViewNewWithBuffer textBuf

    textBufferSetText textBuf "some text"

    boxPackStart menuBox buttonOne PackNatural 0
    boxPackStart menuBox buttonTwo PackNatural 0
    boxPackStart windowBox menuBox PackNatural 0
    boxPackStart windowBox textView PackGrow 0
    set window [containerChild := windowBox]
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "windowBox" is being created with homogeneous set to True. Simply setting this to False will give the desired result:

```
windowBox <- vBoxNew False 2
```

See: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.12.3/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Layout-VBox.html

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question perfectly. I wish I had seen that, I had thought my problem was somewhere with `boxPackStart`!